# "CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(): Wasm code generation disallowed by embedder" In chrome v103+, not occurring in v101

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am using rust wasm to make a chrome extension and I have been running into this problem for a while. Whenever chrome (or edge) is updated past version 101, the wasm does not work. I usually solve this by manually downgrading chrome, but this is annoying and seems like a bug.

Comment: AFAICT now you need to add `script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval';` explicitly to [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy).

Comment: @wOxxOm I added `"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval';",
    "sandbox": ""
  },` to the manifest.json and I am experiencing no changes in behavior. I am new to web development and I don't know if that is how it is supposed to be entered.

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome. See if it's fixed in Chrome Canary or [latest Chromium](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working from @w0xx0m's comment, I started to adjust the content_security_policy in the extension's manifest.json file.

Adding the code below fixed the error.

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; default-src 'self';"
  },
```

Make sure to take note of `default-src 'self';`; the extension will not load without it.

Comment: More info about this: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/sJiaTnFMLHQ/m/y-qT1gplHwAJ